# Facing issues during login with facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I implemented login functionality with Facebook in swift environment. I got success with redirection on Facebook page or Application. After that I am facing issues like "Invalid Scope:Profile".

Does any one having idea. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**Problem is:** 
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your Facebook login method?

Comment: please share code, using screenshot how one can identify issue?

Comment: I am sorry for that ,Company's policy is we can not share a single line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Follow this**

**1) You should add this code on your login with Facebook method**

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
                if (error == nil){
                    let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                    if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                        if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                        {
                            self.getFBUserData()
                            fbLoginManager.logOut()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**2) Make sure your Keychain Sharing must be on**

[image]

Hope these will helpful to you.Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much  @hd1344 . It is working fine and now I am able to get login and fetch the user data from the Facebook.
This answer is perfect for me thanks again.